# PostGIS SFCGAL ERROR: PolyhedralSurface is invalid : inconsistent orientation of PolyhedralSurface detected at edge 0 (0-1) of polygon 3

Tags: postgis, sfcgal, tesselation, postgresql-14

I am trying to [tesselate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) (yes, in the following case the tessellation is perfectly useless, but it's for the purpose of the example), with the help of [`ST_Tesselate()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Tesselate.html) from [SFCGAL](https://oslandia.gitlab.io/SFCGAL/), a polyhedral surface composed of four triangles connected side-by-side and sharing a common summit at the origin (0,0,0) using, e.g. this very simple [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) query:

```
SELECT ST_Tesselate(
    ST_AsText(
        'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
            ((0 0 0, 1 1 1,  1 2 1,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 1 2 1,  3 2 4,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 2 2 1,  3 2 4,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 1 1 1,  2 2 1,  0 0 0))
         )'
     )
);
```

but it returns the following error:

```
NOTICE:  During tesselate(A) :
NOTICE:    with A: POLYHEDRALSURFACE(
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 1/1 1/1 1/1 ,1/1 2/1 1/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)),
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 1/1 2/1 1/1, 3/1 2/1 4/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)),
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 2/1 2/1 1/1 ,3/1 2/1 4/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)),
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 1/1 1/1 1/1, 2/1 2/1 1/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)))

ERROR:  PolyhedralSurface is invalid : inconsistent orientation of PolyhedralSurface
detected at edge 0 (0-1) of polygon 3 : POLYHEDRALSURFACE(
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 1/1 1/1 1/1, 1/1 2/1 1/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)),
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 1/1 2/1 1/1, 3/1 2/1 4/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)),
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 2/1 2/1 1/1, 3/1 2/1 4/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)),
((0/1 0/1 0/1, 1/1 1/1 1/1, 2/1 2/1 1/1, 0/1 0/1 0/1)))
SQL state: XX000
```

But if I only take the two first triangular elements (or also the two last ones), the query is OK:

```
SELECT ST_Tesselate(
    ST_AsText(
        'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
            ((0 0 0, 1 1 1,  1 2 1,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 1 2 1,  3 2 4,  0 0 0))
         )'
     )
);
```

and returns:

[image: pg returns a valid geometry]

Hence the following naive question:
how could I validate or make sure that the geometry is valid before storing it to the database? I'm especially wondering what does the "inconsistent orientation" exactly tells, because all parts are triangles and I cannot imagine that a triangle could have a "wrong" orientation, does it? How then could I take care of the orientation of a triangle defined in 3D space? Is it linked to the other ones or is it totally independent? -- well, it shouldn't be independent, should it?

I've already tried to use the [`ST_IsValid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) function on the geometry but it says:

```
ERROR:  Unknown geometry type: 13 - PolyhedralSurface
SQL state: XX000
```

Info:

```
SELECT version();
"PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit"

SELECT postgis_version();
"3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"

SELECT postgis_sfcgal_version();
"1.3.8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the right way to defin the polyhedral surface:

```sql
SELECT ST_Tesselate(
    ST_AsText(
        'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
            ((0 0 0, 1 1 1,  1 2 1,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 1 2 1,  3 2 4,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 3 2 4,  2 2 1,  0 0 0)), 
            ((0 0 0, 2 2 1,  1 1 1,  0 0 0))
         )'
     )
);
```

which returns:

[image]

I only flipped some coordinates in the last triangles as follow:

[image]

Instead of this in the original query:

[image]

So the order of the coordinates of each face seemed to actually define the orientation of the polyhedral surface.
But it was a trial and error process to find the right solution.

This seems to be confirmed at chapter **6.1.12 PolyhedralSurface** (p.29) of the OGC document titled: "[OpenGIS® Implementation Standard for Geographic
information - Simple feature access - Part 1: Common
architecture](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355)":

[image: Simple feature access - common]

Link to the OGC Simple Feature Access - Part 1: Common Architecture documents:
https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfa